# Convert dict to pandas dataframe with key as column1 and value as col2

Tags: python, pandas

I hava a dictionary: **from_this_dict**.

```py
from_this_dict_ = {"folder1": ["file1", "file2"], "folder2": ["file3"] }
```

I want to convert **from_this_dict** to **to_this_dataframe**, where colum1 is given by the keys ("folders") and column 2 is the values ("filename")

Expected out:

```py
to_this_dataframe = pd.DataFrame({"folders" : ["folder1","folder1","folder2"], "files": ["file1", "file2", "file3"]})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
L = [(k, x) for k, v in from_this_dict_.items() for x in v]

df = pd.DataFrame(L, columns=['folders','files'])
print (df)
   folders  files
0  folder1  file1
1  folder1  file2
2  folder2  file3
```

You could also use the itertools functions `product` and `chain`, which returns the same output as above:

```
pd.DataFrame(chain.from_iterable(product([left], right) 
                                 for left, right 
                                 in from_this_dict_.items()
                                ), 
             columns = ['folders', 'files']
             )

   folders  files
0  folder1  file1
1  folder1  file2
2  folder2  file3
```

Comment: does the same thing; felt it made more sense to add to yours than create a new answer;